# How to share a web app in amazon ec2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I create a free tier ec2 instance in amazon, I reserve a Elastic IP and assign it to my instance.

I install nginx and I need to access nginx from internet, for that I went to my domain registrar godaddy I create a cname that point to this Elastic IP.

I access SSH service using this IP now.

Finally I create a security group, I open stream to HTTP port.
And it seems not working ?

Please can you help me to troubleshoot and find why I can not connect to the web server ?

Comment: can you access it via EIP address? something start from hjttp://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX....?

Comment: Those steps should generally work.  If you ssh to your instance, can you access your web app from there?  (Try using Lynx to at least load the home page).

Comment: @BMW no I can not access it via http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx

Comment: in its security group, open inbound rule to 0.0.0.0/0 to http port 80, then you should be fine to access it. Later you can adjust the CIDR range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step #1:

Test via its EIP address, something likes http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx

If you can't, in its security group, open inbound rule to `0.0.0.0/0` to http port 80, then you should be fine to access it.

Later you can adjust that CIDR range.

#### Step #2:

Access from it domain name which you registered in godaddy, if not, you need review the setting in godaddy and make sure you point to the right IP address.

#### Step #3:

Build a ELB (aws elastic load balancer) in front of nginx web server, then redirect the traffic from ELB to nginx, this way will be more flexable.

Comment: In security grou I found two acl. I already added this rule in the default acl. It seems that it doesn't work. How to test if my security group acl are working

Comment: One way is enable "flows log", but seems it is complex for you.

Comment: and do you set any iptables rule in ec2 instance?